# How can i set color svg file on leaflet?

Tags: javascript, icons, leaflet, openstreetmap, marker

How can I set the fill color on an `SVG` file with leaflet or similar?

```
var svgURL = '../file.svg';
var mySVGIcon = L.icon( {
    iconUrl: svgURL,
    iconSize: [30, 30],
    shadowSize: [12, 10],
    iconAnchor: [5, 5],
    popupAnchor: [5, -5],
} );
```

Comment: Not an answer, but: external SVG files cannot be styled with CSS. Leaflet seems to only support external SVG files. You might want to create a feature request for Leaflet.